# SQL: Create a table with 24 hourly rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

In PostreSQL, it is fairly easy to create a timestamp with date and the current hour:

```
vioozer=> SELECT to_char(NOW(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00');
     to_char
------------------
 2014-08-12 12:00
(1 row)
```

The previous hour can be shown using `NOW()-interval '1 hour'`:

```
vioozer=> SELECT to_char(NOW()-interval '1 hour', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00');
     to_char
------------------
 2014-08-12 11:00
(1 row)
```

Is there a way to easily generate a table with 24 columns for the last 24 hours, a-la:

```
vioozer=> SELECT MAGIC_FROM_STACK_OVERFLOW();
     to_char
------------------
 2014-08-12 12:00
 2014-08-12 11:00
 2014-08-12 10:00
 ...
 2014-08-11 13:00
(24 row)
```

Comment: Try using LOOP in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`

```
select i
from generate_series(current_timestamp - interval '24' hour, current_timestamp, interval '1' hour) i
```

Comment: Excellent! Didn't know that one. Your example actually produces 25 hours, so I fixed to `SELECT to_char(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:00') FROM generate_series(current_timestamp - interval '23' hour, current_timestamp, interval '1' hour) time;`.